# "inline" editing in a mvc 4 list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have a strange problem and I don't know if this is actually possible.
What I want is, to be able to list all the values from my model and and edit them directly in the list.

Here's what I have:

Model Linker:

```
     public class StoreLinkerModel
      {
        //public Guid? id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Stores> StoresAndOpeninghours { get; set; }
      }

public class Stores
  {
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
      {

        var model = new StoreLinkerModel
        {
          StoresAndOpeninghours = new[]
            {
              new Stores()
                {
                  ID = 0,
                  Address = "Enghavevej 70"
                }, 
                new Stores()
                  {
                    ID=1,
                    Address = "Løngangsgade 30"
                  }, 
            }

        };
        return View(model);
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Overview(StoreLinkerModel model)
      {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          var x = "go go go";

        }


        return RedirectToAction("Overview");
      }
```

My overview.aspx page:

```
@model streetoffrs.web.Models.StoreLinkerModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Overview";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_dashboard.cshtml";
}

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.StoresAndOpeninghours)
```

and my EditorTemplate stores.aspx

```
@model streetoffrs.web.Models.Stores

@using (Html.BeginForm("Overview", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "id" + @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ID) }))
{


  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
  <input type="submit" class="left btn btn-primary" value="Ret butiksdata">
}
<br />
```

The list is being generated as it should, and when I hit the first button at the first editorfor it will post the model to my controller, but when I push the 2nd button, the model is null, but the first button still works!

Is this possible at all, if yes what am I missing, if not, tell me how I can accomplish this.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need edit post action like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Overview(StoreLinkerModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var x = "go go go";

    }


    return View(model);
  }
```

the **RedirectToAction** will be go to the first Overview Action,so you will be lost the data.

Comment: That makes sense, but there must be something wrong with the model binding since I'm posting an empty model, and hence with your change get a blank page... Any suggestions on the binding?

Comment: There is something wrong.At "overview.aspx" the Model is Stores,but at Overview post action receive StoreLinkerModel,It's must be null.

Comment: not correct, the overview page takes storelinkermodel and my editortemplate, takes stores, since it's inherited from storelinkermodel